# How to auto register msxml6.dll on Windows Server 2003?

Tags: windows-server-2003, msxml6

I have a I have a component that loads the dll dependêcia Windows: msxml6 and msxml6r.

When I run the installer on Windows Server 2003, it does not work because it does not find the dll msxml6 windows itself.

As a workaround I thought of sending and registering these dll along with my installer, but the following problem occurs when I do this:

---

```
error 
--------------------------- 
C: \ WINDOWS \ system32 \ msxml6.dll 

Unable to register the DLL / OCX: Regsvr32 failed with exit code 0x3. 

Click Retry to try again, Ignore to skip this file (not recommended), or Abort to cancel installation. 
--------------------------- 
Cancel Retry Ignore 
---------------------------
```

Can anyone help me?